# Custom -PassThru Switch For PowerShell Function

Tags: powershell, custom-function

I'm currently working on a new PS module and wrapper script for the creation of VMs and their associated VHDs, and I've realised I need to make use of a custom `-PassThru` switch to pipe the variables from one function to another (unless of course anyone else has any ideas). 
The wrapper script itself is:

```
Get-NewVHDPath -VMName $VMName | Select VMName,FreeSpace,LocalVHDPath,RemotePath,RemoteVHDPath,Server | New-CompanyVHD | New-CompanyVM
```

I need to pass what I select through to both the `New-CompanyVHD` (which works perfectly fine), *and* the `New-CompanyVM` (which complains the value for `$VMName` is `false`, therefore telling me the variables aren't being passed down the pipe and are only being used by the `New-CompanyVHD` function). So, I *think* I need something like:

```
Get-NewVHDPath -VMName $VMName | Select VMName,FreeSpace,LocalVHDPath,RemotePath,RemoteVHDPath,Server | New-CompanyVHD -Passthru | New-CompanyVM
```

I've added a `-PassThru` switch to the `New-CompanyVHD` function in the module, but I'm not sure how I can go about obtaining that information and making it pass through to the next. The function itself is:

```
Function Get-NewVHDPath {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,
            HelpMessage = "Please enter the name of the VM to create.")]
        [string]$VMName,

        [switch]$Passthru)
    $Hypervisors = "Server1", "Server2", "Server3"
    Log "The hypervisors to check are: $Hypervisors"
    Log "Now querying the servers to determine how much space each has..."
    $Space = Try {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Hypervisors | Where {$_.DeviceID -ne "C:"} | Select-Object PSComputerName, DeviceID,
        @{Name = "NSize"; Expression = {[math]::Round(($_.Size / 1GB), 2)}},
        @{Name = "NFreespace"; Expression = {[math]::Round(($_.Freespace / 1GB), 2)}}
    }
    Catch {
        Return $_
    }
    If ($Space) {
        Log "Query succeeded!"
        Log "Now calculating space on $Hypervisor..."
        # Determine the variables for the max drive size, the disk letter, and the server for the new VM
        $Max = ($Space | Measure-Object -Property NFreespace -Maximum).Maximum
        $LocalDrive = ($Space | Where {$_.NFreeSpace -eq $Max}).DeviceID
        $RemoteDrive = $LocalDrive.Replace(":", "$")
        $Server = ($Space | Where {$_.NFreeSpace -eq $Max}).PSComputerName
        $RemotePath = "\\$Server\$RemoteDrive\Virtual Machines"
        $RemoteVHDPath = "$Path\$VMName.vhdx"
        $LocalVHDPath = "$LocalDrive\Virtual Machines\$VMName.vhdx"

        # Output a custom object
        $Properties = @{'VMName' = $VMName;
            'Server' = $Server;
            'RemotePath' = $RemotePath;
            'LocalVHDPath' = $LocalVHDPath;
            'RemoteVHDPath' = $RemoteVHDPath;
            'FreeSpace' = $Max
        }

        $Object = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Properties | Select-Object Server, VMName, RemotePath, LocalVHDPath, RemoteVHDPath, FreeSpace
        Write-Output $Object
    }
    Else {
        Write-Output $Space
        Log "Cannot determine free space on the Hypervisors. Exiting..."
        Break
    }
}
```

Any help with this would of course be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a brain fart on my part...

```
Log "This is a test run! VMname has been set to $VMName!"
```

$VMVar = Get-NewVHDPath -VMName $VMName | Select VMName,VHDSize,Server,LocalVMPath,LocalVHDPath 
$VMVar | New-CompanyVHD 
$VMVar | New-CompanyVM

Works perfectly.